# REST login not working as expected with Interceptors

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cxf, interceptor

I have a REST service using CXF, I have also placed an interceptor to check for basic authentication. When I am trying to access the REST service URL from browser, I did get an message thrown from Interceptor. But I was expecting a normal login popup.

REST service URL

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringRestBasicAuth/api/bookservice/books/1234
```

Error message on accessing the REST service URL:

```
<ns1:XMLFault xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat">
<ns1:faultstring xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat">java.lang.RuntimeException: 401 UNAUTHORIZED</ns1:faultstring>
</ns1:XMLFault>
```

CXF Servlet.XML

```
<jaxrs:server id="bookService" address="/bookservice">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
           <ref bean="bs"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean='jsonProvider' />
        </jaxrs:providers>
        <jaxrs:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="logininterceptor" />
        </jaxrs:inInterceptors>
     </jaxrs:server>

      <bean id="logininterceptor" class="org.gsdev.ws.bookservice.interceptor.AuthenticatorInterceptor"/>
```

AuthenticatorInterceptor class

```
public class AuthenticatorInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

    private Map<String,String> users;

    public void setUsers(Map<String, String> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public AuthenticatorInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.RECEIVE);
        this.users = new HashMap<String, String>();
        this.users.put("test", "test");
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {

        AuthorizationPolicy policy = message.get(AuthorizationPolicy.class);

        if (policy == null) {
                System.out.println("User attempted to log in with no credentials");     
                throw new RuntimeException(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED+" UNAUTHORIZED");    
        }
        System.out.println("Logging in use: " + policy.getUserName());

        // Verify the password
        String realPassword = users.get(policy.getUserName());
        if (realPassword == null || !realPassword.equals(policy.getPassword())) {
            System.out.println("Invalid username or password for user: " + policy.getUserName());
            throw new RuntimeException(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_FORBIDDEN+" FORBIDDEN");
        }

    }
}
```

Can someone guide me so that when anyone tries to access the service URL then should get an normal login popup instead of direct exception message?

Comment: Probably you should provide you request you send to your service. Nevertheless I am curious why you need a popup when accessing a REST-API?

Comment: @questionare.... I updated the question to add the service URL where I am sending 1234 as id/request. I need user to login/authenticate into the service (like standalone) without need to login into the application.

Comment: I still don't get why there should be a login pop up? the behaviour is exactly what u've defined in your service `throw new RuntimeException(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED+" UNAUTHORIZED");` ???? Also I don't see any definition of a loginpage?

Comment: I hope you have seen many standalone services where you need to login. I am not rigid for word popup just need a way to login into the service if you access it from browser. You show me the ways, I am open to learn.

Comment: I don't know why people like to downvote without even knowing the reason.

Answer (score -2):

I think, you cannot send header login information from browser itself and you may need a tool like Postman to send the credentials. Or use any other client like Apache HTTPClient.

Comment: You are totally right, tthats why I told you if you are absoutely sure if you configured postman properly! An easier approach might be curl (https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/curl). Why you don't accept my answer?